# "Cannot find type" error in Azure Pipelines Powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

I am having trouble resolving the following error in a Powershell Script in Azure Pipelines:

```
Cannot find type [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

The context is as follows:

I have written a script that creates and hooks up the Azure AD App Registration for a web application.  I don't want to have to go into the portal and manually delegate that permission, so I am attempting to add a section to my script that will identify the graph API delegated permission that I need to login a user ("User.Read") and automatically assign it to the App Registration.

The following script works if I run it directly in the Azure Portal Cloud Shell:

```
Write-Output "No App Registration found.  We need to create one."
New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $AppService -IdentifierUris "http://$AppService"
Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $AppService | Update-AzADApplication -ReplyUrl @("https://$AppService.azurewebsites.net/$LoginRoute", "https://$HostName/$LoginRoute")
$reg = Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $($AppService)

Write-Output "Now we need to give the app permissions."
# We need to give the app permission to read the user profile
$graphPerms = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$graphPerms.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # graph id, not app registration id
$readUser = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess"
$readUser.Id = "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d" # this is the permanent GUID of the User.Read permission in Graph
$readUser.Type = "Role"
$graphPerms.ResourceAccess = $readUser
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $reg.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $graphPerms
```

However, when I try to run it through the Pipelines Azure Powershell release task, it gives me that "Cannot find type" error.

So, I know what "Cannot find type" means, my question is why is that not available to Pipelines but it is to the Azure Portal Cloud Shell?

And, as an obvious follow-up, is there anything obvious that I am missing that I should try as far as making that type available to my script?

Comment: If the same result persists even in Azure Powershell task, the cause of the issue could be lack of [azure ad module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Hi friend, could my answer help to resolve your puzzle and the issue? Any update feel free to let me know~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I know what "Cannot find type" means, my question is why is that
>   not available to Pipelines but it is to the Azure Portal Cloud Shell?

1.The `Azure Portal Cloud Shell` from Azure contains the required Azure-related modules so you can easily do that using `Azure Portal Cloud Shell`.

2.[Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) is a simple powershell task in Azure Devops Service(Azure Devops Service is **different** product from Azure) which doesn't contain those az modules by default.

3.Comparing with `Powershell task`, [Azure Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops#error-could-not-find-the-modules--with-version--if-the-module-was-recently-installed-retry-after-restarting-the-azure-pipelines-task-agent) contains some az modules by default:

*Azure PowerShell task uses Azure/AzureRM/Az PowerShell Module to interact with Azure Subscription.*

But it doesn't contain the [AzureAD module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) which the missing type belongs to. That's why you get `cannot find type` error in Azure Devops pipeline.

> And, as an obvious follow-up, is there anything obvious that I am
>   missing that I should try as far as making that type available to my
>   script?

A quick workaround is to install the missing AzureAD module. Try something like this:

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser -Force

Import-Module AzureAD -Force

$graphPerms = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
```

Install and then import the module at the start of your script. The issue would go away. (I tested it using VS2017-windows2016 hosted agent with PS task)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am going to test this today and I'll let you know if it solved the problem.  But, yes, I am using the Azure Powershell task.

Comment: Just want to add a gotcha that I discovered:  `"CurrentUser"` (with the quotes) is syntactically valid.  But then it leads to the module being unavailable for import.