# PowerShell command to Create the target resource settings object for a VM in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I am trying to run PowerShell script to Create the target resource settings object for a  VM. But it's throwing error :

PS /home/user> $targetResourceSettingsObj = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings
New-Object: Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ResourceMover.Models.Api202101.VirtualMachineResourceSettings]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I found it's a dependency Assembly needs to be installed for that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.powershell.cmdlets.resourcemover.models.api202101.virtualmachineresourcesettings?view=az-ps-7

How to import it in PowerShell script? I am trying to do this on Azure portal through PowerShell.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925494/cannot-find-type-error-in-azure-pipelines-powershell-script#:~:text=Azure%20PowerShell%20task%20uses%20Azure,error%20in%20Azure%20Devops%20pipeline.

Comment: Are you looking for this config [settings](https://i.imgur.com/vsSbT9z.png) using Powershell?

Comment: My requirement is moving VM from one region to another using PowerShell script and I'm following this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-powershell  but I am blocked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-powershell#:~:text=Create%20the%20target%20resource%20settings%20object%20per%20the%20resource%20you%27re%20moving.%20In%20our%20case%2C%20it%27s%20a%20VM.